# how could the global $user be different between the Drupal interface and Services module?

Tags: users, services, authentication-authorization

If i do:

```
hook_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
        global $user;
        var_dump($user);
        die();
        // i get the correct dump of the current pre-authorized user
}
```

HOWEVER, if I dump `global $user` from one of my public `Service` endpoints an anonymous user. That dump comes from a GET service resource defined as:

```
'retrieve' => array(
       'help' => 'Retrieves a note',
       'file' => array('file' => 'inc', 'module' => 'noteresource'),
       'callback' => '_noteresource_retrieve',
       'access callback' => '_noteresource_access',
       'access arguments' => array('view'),
       'access arguments append' => TRUE,
       'args' => array(
         array(
           'name' => 'id',
           'type' => 'int',
           'description' => 'The id of the note to get',
           'source' => array('path' => '0'),
           'optional' => FALSE,
         )
       )
     )
```

How could that be?

**For my Drupal configuration**: 
I am using `LoginToboggan` and `Generate Password` to handle registrations with only an email address. Alongside I am using the `Services` module which drives the API for our mobile app to tell the app if the user is logged in or not.

Under /admin/config/system/**logintoboggan** I have:

> - I have "Set password" checked
> - a "pre-authorize" permission selected for the "non-authenticated" role prior to email validation.
> - I "never delete" unvalidated users
> - I allow "immediate login" checked

Under /admin/config/people/**accounts** (regarding passwords), I have:

> - Selected "Users may enter a password on registration. If left empty, a random password will be generated. This always applies when an administer is
>     creating the account."
> - Selected "Do not display" under generated password display.

The flow works well from the Drupal interface. That is, the registration is successful, the email is sent, and the user is logged immediately with the pre-authorize role applied even before validating their email. HOWEVER, my API endpoints still show that same user as `anonymous` users session when accessing it with `global $user`. I can literally reload the two pages as if there were no connection between them.

I have cleared all caches.
I have weight-ordered the roles with `pre-authorzed` 2nd, after `anonymous` and before `authenticated user`
I have verified the JS cookies are identical between the API page and Drupal interface  (see the side by side comparison in the screenshots below) and that the $_SESSION globals shows nothing pre-authorized or more.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Is there another way I should access the pre-authorized user other than global $user?

Comment: your services endpoints configuration is very important here. what are they ? your services user will always be anon until they are logged in and have a valid cookie. Are you using the user login service first ?

Comment: @user1081275: my endpoint is `/js-api/note/getme.json`. Where basically i do `noteresource_get_note($id='getme'){return $user}`. Are cookies from Services separarte from the Drupal interface?

Answer (score 0):

Nice question!
After reading your question.
you are not logged in to your app because you are sending the anonymous requests after login.
Workflow should be like this : 
1)User register on the site.you will get the session id and session name.
2)Now need to set the session id and session name in headers then send the requests. you can check the same in drupal logs that whether your requests are coming from anonymous user or authenicated user.
if drupal getting the requests from anonymous user then make sure that headers are properly set. See the [services module documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/736522) to learn out about this.
**Browser tools** :

1. The [Poster add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/) for Firefox.
2. The [REST Console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn) app for Chrome.

if you are using the services module then take a look at its [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/736522)

Comment: thank you! I've posted a screenshot of two tabs comparing cookies. They have identical session IDs.

Comment: It seems to me that the cookies are going fine in both screenshots.
In the function call back of this service /js-api/node/getme.json 
Make sure you are getting the proper uid corresponding to that session parameters ? 
Check in your function callback ?
R u using services module ?

Comment: i am using the Services module. I've updated the question to include my resource definition

Comment: check the services call(by which user) on the drupal site by enabling the debugging in the service endpoint.

Comment: great point @Naveen, i have enabled debugging no the endpoint. However, still none of the services logs tell me anything alluding to an error or user's session.

Comment: Read the documentation of the Services module that I have specified above.you will get to know how to check the service calls

Comment: lol. @naveen, look at the question above. not only have i read that and many docs on Services, you might notice my code here has the same names as the source in one of those doc's tutorials

Comment: (sorry @naveen, i appreciate your effort but this is crazy frustrating)

Comment: phew, It seems that this is not a cup of tea without viewing the code & other configuration stuff.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18792/discussion-between-naveen-valecha-and-eli-a-taylor).

Comment: naveen, i have a little code cred' in the original StackOverflow.com site, but nothing on Drupal. It won't let me chat there without 20 points.

Comment: ok :( wait for some other volunteer to take a look at this question.Wait anyone else will take you out from this issue :)

Comment: hey @Naveen Valecha, i'm back on this and still stuck. I've added a screenshot above of the Services debugger. Can you quickly take a look at those messages and see if anything stands out. To me it looks like everything worked fine, i 'started a session', but then on the right screen using PostMan to /drupalgap/system/connect.json i just get an anonymous user