# How do I edit the response of successful register.json?

Tags: 7, users, services, sessions, authentication-authorization

How can you edit the Services' json response of successful register.json to include the user's OR system's auto-generated password, plus any token?

I've tried a variety of combinations of the commented code below..

```
function logintoboggan_process_login($account, &$edit, $redirect = array()){
  global $user;

  $user = user_load($account->uid);
  watchdog('login debug', json_encode($edit)); // AT THIS POINT I CAN VERIFY WE HAVE THE PLAIN-TEXT PASSWORD
  //user_login_submit(array(), array('uid' => $account->uid));
  user_login_finalize($edit);  
//  $user = user_load($account->uid);
//  $user->token = drupal_get_token('services'); //WE HAVE A TOKEN ALTHOUGH I DOUBT THIS WOULD WORK.
//  user_login_finalize($edit);
//  module_invoke_all('hook_user_login');
//  module_invoke_all('tripchi_user_login');
//  module_invoke_all('logintoboggan_user_login');
```

and even also tried hacking the drupal core on line 3888 of "/modules/user/user.module":

```
elseif (!$admin && !variable_get('user_email_verification', TRUE) && $account->status) {
      global $user;    
      $user = user_load($account->uid);
      watchdog('login debug', json_encode($edit));  // AT THIS POINT I CAN VERIFY WE HAVE THE PLAIN-TEXT PASSWORD AND TOKEN AVAILBABLE!
      //user_login_submit(array(), array('uid' => $account->uid));
      user_login_finalize($edit);  
    //  $user = user_load($account->uid);
    //  $user->token = drupal_get_token('services'); //WE HAVE A TOKEN ALTHOUGH I DOUBT THIS WOULD WORK IN TERMS OF SESSION PERSISTANCE
    //  user_login_finalize($edit);
    _user_mail_notify('register_no_approval_required', $account);
    $form_state['uid'] = $account->uid;
    user_login_submit(array(), $form_state);
    drupal_set_message(t('Registration successful. You are now logged in.'));
    $form_state['redirect'] = '';
  }
```

if one of my test lines don't break the call altogether, on success the call just replies:

```
{
    "uid": "499",
    "uri": "http://localdrupal.tripchi.com/drupalgap/user/499"
}
```

Comment: Does the register resource usually return the full account object? If so you can use `hook_services_account_object_alter()` to decorate it before return

Comment: @Clive, using the basic "notesource" module given in a popular Services tutorial, I added:

`function noteresource_services_account_object_alter(&$edit,    $account, $category) {
    die(__FUNCTION__);
    $edit->token = drupal_get_token('services');
    $edit->password = 'temppasswordwhenotprovided';
    $account->token = drupal_get_token('services');
    $account->password = 'temppasswordwhenotprovided';
}`

but get nothing and it doesn't seem to execute at all.

Comment: @E.A.T are you able to alter register response?

Comment: @Smalution, NO. not within logintoboggan. I ended up adding a `hook_services_resource` endpoint that overwrites the response altogether.

Comment: @E.A.T thanks for reply. i mean you have created custom services for registration right? if yes and you have some docs or reference please share it.

Comment: @Smalution, i hope that answer helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was never able to get back the raw text password without hacking on the logintoboggan / user modules themselves (similar to what is shown in my question).

However, I solved my same purpose of providing immediate-login-upon-registration for Services/API calls using the [services_token_access](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_token_access) module. This code only hooks onto a success registration then ads the services_token to the response which is now the only thing my client now needs for validation.

```
function HOOK_services_request_postprocess_alter($controller, $args, &$result) {

if ( gettype($result) == 'array' && isset($result['uri']) && isset($result['uid'])) { // THIS CONDITION MATCHES THE DEFAULT RESPONSE OF A SUCCESSFUL REGISTRATION. 
        $user = (object)$result;
        $user = user_load($user->uid);
        $user = HOOK_services_account_object_alter($user);
        $result = array('token'=>$user->services_token, 'user'=>$user);
    }
    return $result;
}


function HOOK_services_account_object_alter(&$user) {
    $user->services_token = services_token_access_update_token($user->uid, FALSE); // essential for logging in later
    $user->specialstuff = 'whatever else you need';
    return $user;
}
```

(The services_token_access module is not particularly popular and barely supported, but worked for me.)

Comment: Definitely i will implement it and come back to you. Thank you very much.

Comment: you are great. It solved my requirement related to registration API. Thank you so much.